# How to use ssh credentials in Jenkins job from execute shell command

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-plugins

I've been trying without luck to allow Jenkins to connect to an SSH server from within an execute shell command.

I've installed the SSH Credentials plugin and have added a credential for the SSH site - including the key.  I've given the credential an ID of my-server-ssh - thinking that this is how I can refer to it from the execute shell command - but I think that might be where I'm wrong.

From the execute shell command, I'm doing this:

```
ssh my-server-ssh ls
```

But that is producing this error:
ssh: Could not resolve hostname my-server-ssh: Name or service not known

So it appears that specifying the ID doesn't work.  Has anyone had any success doing something similar?

Comment: Are you running this on the master node or a agent node?  Can you try to run the ssh command directly from the node itself ( ssh into the node, then run your ssh command outside of jenkins ) to see if that server can reach that domain?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by following the instructions [on this page](https://thelinuxgurus.com/jenkins-server-simple-guide-to-add-ssh-credentials-in-jenkins-server/).  Instead of putting the credentials into the global credentials section, I added them from the Configure System - SSH Servers section.  The other mistake I was making was thinking that I can use the name as defined in SSH Servers as the name of the server from my SSH command.  Instead, the username and URL of the server need to be specified in the command itself - and I was able to connect to the server.